# Firebase Phone Authentication just timing out and not sending SMS or Auto Login

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have implemented the Firebase phone authentication on my flutter application. But anytime I send invoke the `initAuth` method, I get `code sent` on my console then after 60 secs `timed out`. That I understand is simply coming from my code but I expected an SMS or an auto login. It seems I don't ever get the `verificationCompleted` method invoked.

Below is my code:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PhoneVerification{
  initAuth({BuildContext context, String phoneNumber}) async{
    print(phoneNumber);
    var firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
      codeSent:(String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]){
        print("Code Sent");
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId){
        print("Timed out");
      },
      verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential auth) async {
        print("This User is authenticated by google play services");
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(auth)
            .then((AuthResult result) =>{
              if(result != null && result.user != null){
                print("Authentication is Successful")
              }else{
                print("Authentication failed!")
              }
        })
            .catchError((error){
              print(error);
            });
        },
      verificationFailed: (AuthException authException){
        print('Error message: ' + authException.message);
      },
    );
  }
  
}
```

This is the method I wrote to invoke the `initAuth` method:

```dart
  Future<void> sendSMS({context}) async{
    User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).user;
    PhoneVerification phoneVerification = PhoneVerification();
    await phoneVerification.initAuth(context: context, phoneNumber: user.phone);
  }
```

Then finally, I am making the actual call onPress of a button in a component. Below is how I invoked the `sendSMS` method.

```dart
EnterPhone(onPress: ()=> sendSMS(context: context)),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for me :

```
// For firebase auth
final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
//
final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
    (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
  final res = await auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
  // Todo After Verification Complete
  );
};
//
final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
    (AuthException authException) {
  print('Auth Exception is ${authException.message}');
};
//
final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
    (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
  print('verification id is $verificationId');
  verId = verificationId;
};
//
final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
    (String verificationId) {
  verId = verificationId;
  
};
//
await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    // mobile no. with country code
    phoneNumber: '+91${_mobile.text}',
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
    verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: codeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
```

Comment: Ha ha ha, it's weird why I am using an async function and chaining `.then`. I would try that immediately ad give you my feedback. Thank you

Comment: Well as I thought, I got the same response. I guess, it's the same thing just that I replaced the promise chaining with the await. This would only require that I wrap it in a `try catch` since it can throw an exception

Comment: maybe u r not calling it the right way add code for calling this method

Comment: So I realised it was nothing about the code, I added the number I was using as a default number and added a code manually on the firebase console so that's why it wasn't sending the SMS. But I have retained your code because I think it looks a lot cleaner than the way I implemented it Earlier. Thank you so much :)